# Redshift DateAdd

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to get first date of the month.

condition is : (current month - 36)  so i have written like DATEADD(month, -36, getdate()) but it is giving the date like 2018-06-22 00:00:00
but I need the output like 2018-06-01 00:00:00

Br,
Satish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [date_trunc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_TRUNC.html):

```
date_trunc('month', DATEADD(month, -36, getdate()))
```